# Can't install heroku toolbelt on Linux Mint Path invalid

Tags: linux, bash, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

Attemping

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

as instructed by this [article](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) yields this message.

```
Add the Heroku CLI to your PATH using: $ echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

So I type

```
echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

and I see that the string has been added to the .profile file, located at `/home/myusername/`

Then I run the command again

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

and I still get the same error.

I'm not sure if what current directory I'm running these commands from is important, but I've tried being in the default terminal directory, rather than my specific app, and still the same results.

I found out that the `/usr/` directory is directly underneath the `/` directory, NOT my `/home/myusername/` directory so I modified the path to go up two levels, first like so:

```
PATH="../../usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

But even that didn't seem to work - I don't get the "heroku" command available.

Comment: You seem pretty confused about paths. 1) This is not an error message.  It's just telling you that to run the command heroku..., you must put it in your path. 2) The echo command **does** add /usr/local...  This is not under your home directory. 3) Did you do the installation with sudo?  Unless you're logged in as root, you probably need it. Did you start a new shell after changing the PATH variable? This is necessary. Else you must source your .profile. Say printenv PATH to see what's what. 4) To be successful at Rails development you will need to pause and learn some Linux first.

Comment: Thank you for the `printenv PATH` hint. I  don't see the heroku path in that list. How do I get the .profile script to run to actually add the additional path to the list of paths?

Comment: There isn't a problem here. It tells you to add it to your path as a post-install message, and you did.

Comment: As I said, a new shell will read your .profile unless you are not using a conventional shell (like bash).  If you start a new bash and the path is still wrong, then there's something wrong with .profile that you'll have to fix.

Comment: I did not know what sourcing was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to log into linux profile again to activate the ~/.profile script, thus adding the path. Either log out of the linux session, and then lack back in, or restart your computer.

You can also do `source ~/.profile`, but this will only enable heroku commands in the current terminal, and not work if you close it.